# How do I refer to an <iframe>'s document using jQuery to get its height()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, document

I'm trying to get the height of an <iframe>d document. My first instincts were:

```
$('iframe').document.height();
```

or

```
$('iframe').contentWindow.document.height();
```

Those don't work, and I'm not having much luck searching. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

```
$("iframe",top.document).contents().height();
alert("iframe height=" + $("iframe",top.document).height());
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, but that didn't work for me (at least in Firefox). I get this exception:

[Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0" nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)" location: "JS frame :: http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js :: anonymous :: line 12" data: no]

If I assign that to a variable as such:

var height = $("iframe", top.document).contents().height();

it remains undefined after the assignment and causes the above exception.

Comment: Also, this:

$("iframe", top.document).height();

appears to just give me the height of the <iframe>, not the document that it contains. I just realized that I might have missed an important detail, or at least have been unclear - I'm trying to get this height from the parent document of the <iframe>, not from within the <iframe> itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("iframe").bind('mouseover', function(){
        alert($(this).contents().height());
    });

});
```